# How to convert, nvarchar to car number type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some car numbers in my database and I want to change it's structure like that

`AA11BB` => `AA-11-BB`

`A111BB` => `A-111-BB`

`AAA111` => `AAA-111`

Etc.

can I achieve this only using by SQL?

### DDL

```
declare @a table (
    CN varchar(20)
)

insert  @a
values  ('AA11BB'),
        ('A111BB'),
        ('AAA111')
```

Comment: This would be tough to do in SQL Server, and you'd probably be better off handling this before you bring the data into your table.

Comment: It can be simply done via Regular Expressions. Although it would be much simpler with programming language Python, JavaScript, PHP, Java, etc. It could be done in SQL, take a look at this docs - https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL

Comment: Are there only the three possible scenarios?  What if the data was A1A111?

Comment: my answer works for all variants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple query to see how it works. The problem is solved using `patindex` which can return index of an regular expression within a given string.

```
declare @s varchar(10) = 'AAA111'

select case when [i2] > 0 then stuff(s, [i2] + 1, 0, '-')  else s end [s] from (
    select case when [i1] > 0 then stuff(s, [i1] + 1, 0, '-')  else s end [s],
           PATINDEX('%[0-9][A-Z]%', case when [i1] > 0 then stuff(s, [i1] + 1, 0, '-')  else s end) [i2]
    from (
        select @s [s], PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%', @s) [i1]
    ) a
) a
```

In order to you use it in your DB, replace `@s` by your column name in the subquery and add `from MY_TABLE`, to specify from what table column is taken.

Answer (score 2):

This would only work for the patterns you supply, other patterns would not be changed:

```
declare @a table (
    CN varchar(20)
)

insert  @a
values  ('AA11BB'),
        ('A111BB'),
        ('AAA111')

select  CN,
        case when CN like '[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][a-z][a-z]' then left(CN,2) + '-' + substring(CN,3,2) + '-' + right(CN,2)
        --Your other scenarios in here
        else CN
        end
from @a
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to make as method

```
 DECLARE @txt varchar(100) = 'A1A111';

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @a1 int = (SELECT ISNULL(PATINDEX('%[A-Z][0-9]%', @txt), 0));
        DECLARE @a2 int = (SELECT ISNULL(PATINDEX('%[0-9][A-Z]%', @txt), 0));
        DECLARE @Dashnumber int = (SELECT CASE WHEN @a1 > 0 THEN @a1 + 1 WHEN @a2 > 0 THEN @a2 + 1 ELSE 0 END);

        IF (@Dashnumber = 0) BREAK;

        SET @txt = STUFF(@txt, @Dashnumber, 0, '-');        
    END

    SELECT @txt
```